# Add georeferenced image to power bi report

Tags: image, powerbi, scatter-plot

I hope you can help me.
What I want to do is a scatter plot that represents the x and y coordinates of dumps but also insert into this chart a georeferenced image in order to see the dumps in this image.
Is it possible to do this?

What I did is insert map chart but it show me a very old picture that is why I would like to import a recent one with a georeferenced image.
I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at https://icon-map.com/ a PBI map visual, this may suit your requirement